# Android Studio guideline header percentage not working

Tags: android, android-studio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="323dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintL
```

I want to use a guideline in Android Studio in a percentage form. but when I click on the header of the vertical guideline to change it to a percentage, it won't change, but surprisingly the horizontal one changes easily to percentage mode!! why does it happen?

Comment: Could you show `xml` that used `guildline`?

Comment: Please provide relevant code

Comment: xml added to the post

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to set percent of `guideline`, you should use `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent`
- `orientaion` means guideline's orientaion

  - you can think `guideline` is like a (Invisible)`View`
  - `android:orientation="horizontal"` -> `guideline` is horizontal line -> you can set other view **vertically** by this
  - vice versa

for example

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.48" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.73" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```